# regarding the output of counting the unique numbers of multi-dimension array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

There is a multi-dimensional array generated from a prediction model. I would like to check the values of this array. Here is my code.

```
    print('Predictions shape ',predictions.shape)        
    unique_items, counts = np.unique(predictions,return_counts=True)        
    print('unique_items ',unique_items)
    print('counts ',counts)
```

This is the result. I do not quite understand the output item marked with yellow. Why it cannot give the exact value instead of `1...`. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: the `...` are not value estimation. It simply means the array was concatenated to fit on screen. Only the first few and last few elements are displayed.

Comment: You wonder why the print output looks like this? This is only because the length of the array is too long for the console. Try it `print unique_items[0:5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the print output of a numpy array.

You can set the `linewidth` and `edgeitems` yourself [numpy.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(linewidth=1000, edgeitems=5)

predictions = np.random.rand(3249, 4096, 2)

print('Predictions shape ',predictions.shape)        
unique_items, counts = np.unique(predictions,return_counts=True)        
print('unique_items ',unique_items)
print('counts ',counts)
```

Another way would be to convert `np.array` to `list` and print that ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html))

```
# beware, this takes like forever :)
print('unique_items ',unique_items.tolist())
print('counts ',counts.tolist())
```